# How to selectively prevent Terraform config from being passed based on variable?

Tags: terraform, amazon-sqs, terraform-provider-aws

**Context:**

I have a use case where I need to make lots of AWS SQS queues using the `aws_sqs_queue` resource.

Some of these SQS queues need to be specified to use a DLQ, and some of the queues being made are DLQ's.

In order to specify a target DLQ, one needs to provide a redrive_policy of the form:

```
redrive_policy = jsonencode({
    deadLetterTargetArn = var.dlq_arn
    maxReceiveCount = var.max_receive_count
})
```

**Problem:**

The `redrive_policy` shouldn't be included if the queue being made is itself a DLQ, since DLQ's don't need another DLQ for themselves.

In my `variables.tf` I specify the type of `deadLetterTargetArn` as string with a default of `null`.

I fear that this will result in a DLQ failing to be created because no `deadLetterTargetArn` gets passed in but a `maxReceiveCount` is still expected and the `redrive_policy` will become invalid JSON.

Should I be using a conditional here? What is the correct approach for selectively enabling certain parts of config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be using a conditional here?

Yes. That's exactly what you should do:

```
redrive_policy = dlq_arn != null ? jsonencode({
    deadLetterTargetArn = var.dlq_arn
    maxReceiveCount = var.max_receive_count
}) : null
```

Comment: Shouldn't the == be != ? We only want to assign a redrive_policy if the queue is not a DLQ, which means the value of dlq_arn would have to be a valid arn (error checking aside)

Comment: @PrithviBoinpally Yes. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a separate variable in every queue resource instead of dlq_arn, where redrive policy will only come into effect when the var's value is false. The rest of @Marcin's suggestion will remain the same:

> redrive_policy = is_dlq == 0 ? jsonencode({....